# ASP.NET Core Web API : xmlns was not expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, xml-formatting

I am trying to build a API which will take XML as request data.

My controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/MyApi/CalculateMyPrice")]
public virtual ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> CalculateMyPrice(Request request)
{}
```

My model classes are :

```
public partial class Request 
{ 
    public RequestHeader ReqHdr { get; set; } 
}

public partial class RequestHeader
{
    public string MsgId { get; set; }
}
```

and my XML format setup :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
}
```

But when I try to access this method using POSTMAN I am getting this error:

[image]

> InvalidOperationException: `<Request xmlns='urn:com.mysystems:api-message.002'>` was not expected.

But when I remove `xmlns=` from request XML, I get the proper response.

Maybe I am missing something here? Any ideas?

Comment: The URL of the namespace doesn't look correct : uri:com.myststems:api-nessage.002

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When applying an `xml namespace` in the `xml` payload, you must also indicate that the corresponding model/class is using and is expecting this namespace.

To do so, you decorate your class with an `XmlRootAttribute`.

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace ="urn:com.mysystems:api-message.002")]
public partial class Request
{
    public RequestHeader ReqHdr { get; set; }
}

public partial class RequestHeader
{
    public string MsgId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thank you sir,  how to accept List object ?


public List<RequestHeader> ReqHdr { get; set; }